# scrollIntoView() is not working outside the debugger

Tags: javascript, extjs, view, scroll, extjs6

I have one window with `border` layout. In center I am using  panel on which loading grids based on the selection of tabs from west side. Now the problem is when I am loading grid then grids are one on top of another. And then I need to scroll down to check complete grid. I want to see grid in panel if suppose i sellect second tab, first grid should move up and second grid should come into view.

I have used many methods but not getting success.

One of the code where I am getting bit of success,

```
onSelectionBtnClick : function(btn){
             grid = me.someGrid(headersNode);
            me.gridContainer.setLoading(false);
            grid.body.dom.scrollIntoView(); // This line is for view

}
```

Here grid is coming in view but only in debugger, once I come out from debugger It coming same as previous. Can any body suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: any luck finding the solution?